# Show a variable from one JS file to another JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, ecmascript-6

I have a node.js controller that  create a csv file and it is stored in a specific folder, there is also a value from a var called endpoint.

The thing is that in the end of the lines of the controller i have this start function to start another process in another javascript file called bot.js

```
const scrapeWebsite = require('../bot')
const start = new scrapeWebsite();

    var endpoint ="192.186.1.1"
try {
        start.init();
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(e, null, 5))
    }
```

In the bot.js file i want to access the value of the endpoint variable of my controller.js to use it in the bot function process and i dont know how to do  this.

like declare a new var in the bot.js with the same value as the endpoint in the controller.js

```
class scrapeWebsite {
    init() {
   
        this.startScrape()
    }

    async startScrape() {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export that function from bot.js
`module.exports.function_name = function_name`

And when you want to run it in node.js controller, import it using
`const {function_name} = require("../bot")`

And when you want to execute that function, call that function
`function_name(<with, arguments, from, bot.js, file>)`